# Get messages.log style logging out of embedded neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

How can I maximize the log information an embedded neo4j database will give me, so that I can see what's going on?

Recent technical discussion on the google group called for an excerpt of messages.log, but I don't have that log file since I'm running embedded.   I have consulted the server configuration docs (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html#_server_logging_configuration) but they don't tell me the actual names of the loggers to use.

I have tried this:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.neo4j").setLevel(Level.ALL)
```

But by default, and also with this line of code, I see no log messages from neo4j at all.

I'm trying to get some of the server message logs to debug why certain read-only transactions are failing and rollback is failing; first I have to figure out how to get neo4j to tell me what's going on in this embedded database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have `messages.log` it is in your `graph.db` directory.

And there are loads of diagnostic, config, tuning, memory and other information in that file. So very valuable.

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking and looking, and this wasn't clear from docs.  But I'll go dig it up now.